# Similar MySQL queries returning with different sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-concat

I've two queries which should both return thumbUrls in the same order. My goal is to use the second query, as it has to be part of another query, which won't work with the first one. I already broke down the queries, but couldn't find what's casing the difference.

---

**Query One:**

```
SELECT album, thumbUrl
FROM lychee_photos
WHERE album = '16'
ORDER BY takestamp ASC, id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| album | thumbUrl                              |
-------------------------------------------------
| 16    | 48c4d04567590b44a0c604197a049ef5.jpeg |
| 16    | 5db0fce4937104e7d27dae64d6cd9990.jpeg |
| 16    | a70bb8499b683b1eeab17336c3f07f7e.jpeg |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**Query Two:**

```
SELECT album, substring_index(
    GROUP_CONCAT(thumbUrl ORDER BY takestamp ASC, id DESC), ',', 3
) AS thumbs
FROM lychee_photos
WHERE album='16'
GROUP BY album;
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| album | thumbUrl                                                                                                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16    | 1b98e17f1af051753a958c18953adbd5.jpeg,c506f4fedb8a4df691d276d6abdb75f7.jpeg,f0cc0ba23effc0443f367ca63dd1e72f.jpeg |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Expected output:**

I expected to see thumbUrls in the same order as in query one.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| album | thumbUrl                                                                                                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16    | 48c4d04567590b44a0c604197a049ef5.jpeg,5db0fce4937104e7d27dae64d6cd9990.jpeg,a70bb8499b683b1eeab17336c3f07f7e.jpeg |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Additional details:**

- Data hasn't changed between the queries
- Removing `substring_index()` doesn't affect the order
- The correct thumbUrls appear in the middle of query two, when I remove `substring_index()`

---

The first query returns correctly sorted thumbUrls—the second don't. But why? How do I keep the output format of the second one and get a correct sorting?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more context. What is your expected output? What does the data look like that you are performing the query on? The two rows don't even have the same file names listed, so I am very unclear on what you are trying to do, and what the issue is.

Comment: Expected output has been added.

Comment: Has your data changed between the time you ran query 1 and query 2? Can you share sample data from that table (include fields album, thumburl, takestamp and id)?

Comment: The data hasn't been changed between the two queries. Need to break down the table before I can paste it. Would add to much complexity otherwise. My initial thought was that my query is simply incorrect and I'm over seeing something.. That's why I haven't included any data, yet.

Comment: If you remove the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function from the second query, do the desired results appear in the output at all?  Does `SHOW WARNINGS;` after the second query reveal any warnings?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot They appear when I remove `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, but they are still in the wrong order. Removing `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` doesn't affect the order :-/

Comment: @tobi what you're doing here in query 2 seems valid -- perhaps not terribly efficient, but legitimate.  If there's a conceptual error or logical flaw, it doesn't jump out at me... so, your best bet would be to try to replicate this behavior with a small but suitable data set, at http://sqlfiddle.com, then share the link so the rest of us can see what you see.  This could also be an optimizer bug. Provide the output from `SELECT @@VERSION;` please.